# Regex - First letter of every word and Last word

Tags: regex

I want to take first letter of every words and combine with last word.
But want to keep the digit if there's any
To illustrate :

> **L**YNDON **B** **J**OHNSON **FWY** -> LBJ FWY
>   **N** **J**OSE **F** **S**AN **N**ICHOLAS **ST** -> NJFSN ST
>   **U**NIT **100034** -> U 100034
>   **L**YNDON **B** **J**OHNSON **123** **FWY** -> LBJ 123 FWY

I've tried with different ways but seems like doesn't work:

```
([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]+)\s(\w+)$
```

Please refer to the [link for my Regex](https://regex101.com/r/g0kveP/1)

Comment: Try a PCRE pattern like `\b([a-zA-Z])\w*+(?!$)(?:\h++(?!\w+$))?`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nTy484/1).

Comment: It's not quite right, second line should be `LBJ 123 FWY` not `LBJ123 FWY`

Comment: Not sure of the actual requirements then. Where can the numbers be? If before the final word, try `\b([a-zA-Z])\w*+(?!$)(?:\h++(?!(?:\d+\h+)?\w+$))?`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nTy484/2).

Comment: Best I can do is special-case the word before the last word or digits `([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]* (?=.* )(?!\d)|([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]*(?= \d+ | [a-zA-Z\d]+$)`, https://regex101.com/r/1irrfz/1

Comment: If nothing from above works, try also `\b([a-zA-Z])\w*+(?!$)(?:\h++(?!\d+(?!\S)|\w+$))?`. Please clarify the requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your answer. This is what i wanted!

Comment: @Nick your answer works like charm too! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If lookaheads are supported, you might use 2 capturing groups and in the replacement use those 2 groups.

```
\b(?!\w+$)([a-zA-Z])\w* ?(?!\d+\b|\w+$)( \d+)?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?!\w+$)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not 1+ word chars at the end of the string
- `([a-zA-Z])` Capture group 1, match a-zA-Z
- `\w* ?` Match 0+ word chars and optional space
- `(?!\d+\b|\w+$)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right are not only digits  or 1+ word chars at the end of the string
- `( \d+\b)?\b` Optional capture group 2, match a space and 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zmj0XJ/1)

In the replacement use `$1$2`